# Why does HttpClientHandler have both Proxy and UseProxy properties?

Tags: c#, .net

Why is it that having a Proxy property would not be enough?

If it is `null`, then don't use the proxy, if it is `non-null`, then use the provided proxy.

Comment: I imagine one reason might be so you could have a proxy defined ... but toggle it enabled/disabled as needed.  See also  [IWebProxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebproxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "The GetProxy method can be used to control proxy use based on the destination URL...".  Again: you can have a proxy defined, and still have granular runtime control over how - or if - you want it used.

Comment: @alex,  What about using IE's default proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Proxy` property allows you specify a proxy to use by the `HttpClientHandler`.

`UseProxy` property allows indicates whether the handler uses a proxy for requests.

But if you want to use the default proxy, you don't have to defined it in `Proxy` property, is enough with set `UseProxy`.

When `UseProxy` is `true` and `Proxy` is `null`, the `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` is used.

`DefaultWebProxy` property reads proxy settings from the config file. If there is no one, the current user's *Internet Explorer (IE)* proxy settings are used.

Comment: I wonder why Proxy does not have a value of WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy by default, so that you can either set it to null or replace with different proxy

Comment: @alex: probably a matter of design, If I don't want to use a proxy, have more sense don't do anything rather than set Proxy to null and probably is easier set Proxy once and activate/desactivate it with UseProxy than keeping the reference to the proxy to set it in the property.