# How to correctly specify proxy with System.Net.HttpClient

Tags: asp.net, web-config, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.7.1

Can anyone answer whether or not an HttpClient should be using default proxy if specified within web.config?

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy proxyaddress="http://my.proxy" bypassonlocal="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Whenever I use HttpClient I find myself having to implement a static HttpClientHandler

```
private static HttpClientHandler statichandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HttpClientProxy"].ToString()),
            UseProxy = true,
};
```

Is there a way to force httpclient to pickup system.net default config sections/What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution on your own?  I'm working in an application which makes external http requests via several different libraries.  WCF connections properly use the <defaultProxy>, yet HttpClient does not.

Comment: I continued to use the solution as above. In an ideal world it would have used the default proxy.... most annoying. I wrapped around it a check to see if app setting was specified or not.... however if your using third party libraries you may hit a block.

Comment: Actually the following post I believe answers the question, something I'll be referencing tomorrow. I just put a work around in place and you've prompted me to review.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803578/why-does-httpclienthandler-have-both-proxy-and-useproxy-properties

Comment: Thanks, I ended up coming to the same conclusion.  It looks like my edit to my comment didn't persist.  I found that for some reason our code had set UseProxy to false.  Set to true HttpClient respected the default proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual solution was to implement Httpclient with HttpClientHandler, explicitly setting UseProxy to true.

```
private static HttpClientHandler statichandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
   UseProxy = true
};
```

This then picked up the following:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy proxyaddress="http://my.proxy" bypassonlocal="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```